# Where to find a complete "hello world" example/tutorial for XBMC addon development?

Tags: plugins, xbmc

I'd like to start studying xmbc plugin development.

I read official documents, but I'm asking you if there are some resource taking a really step-by-step into an hello-world example.

I google for very long time yesterday and today but I'm not able to have a full picture of the development process.

I'm looking for detailed information about:

- directory structure
- creating the simplest GUI for an hello world (no alert, a Window)
- code with explanations
- creating a zip
- installing via repository
- ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best resources I can point to is:
http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on_development

It provides a lot of information which should be good for your first steps.

And of course the forum is a goog place to gather information:
http://forum.xbmc.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=26

Answer (score 5):

I'm from the Kodi/XBMC team and have just updated the Hello World tutorial on our wiki:

http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:HelloWorld_addon

Its a work in progress but hopefully should be a good starting point for anyone writing an add-on.

We have other tutorials as well on our main developers page:

http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on_development